# My dataframe has many (192) columns. How to select two columns at time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

My dataframe is like `df.columns= ['Time1','Pmpp1','Time2',..........,'Pmpp96']` I want to select two successive columns at a time. Example, `Time1`,`Pmpp1` at a time. 
My code is:

```
for i,j in zip(df.columns,df.columns[1:]):
    print(i,j)
```

My present output is:

```
 Time1 Pmmp1
 Pmmp1 Time2
 Time2 Pmpp2
```

Expected output is:

```
 Time1 Pmmp1
 Time2 Pmpp2
 Time3 Pmpp3
```

Comment: do you knwo in advance the name of the columns?

Comment: Yes, I do know them. Example case is given above.

Comment: I have modified my question, please check again.

Comment: you might consider to remove `python-3.x` tag and, eventually, add `pandas`.

Comment: @user32185, I did edit my tags. I am just curious and new to this platform. How does it matter.

Comment: the `dataframe` tag could be related to other languages and it has about 15x less watchers than `pandas`. Using appropriate tags it help you to get more answer and other users who have similar problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're zipping on the list, and the same list starting from the second element, which is not what you want. You want to zip on the uneven and even indices of your list. For example, you could replace your code with:

`for i, j in zip(df.columns[::2], df.columns[1::2]):
    print(i, j)`

Comment: Thanks for response. But, it is giving error as `invalid syntax`. Could you check it again.

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-5-fa22c951700e>", line 18
    for
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Post a complete code sample that reproduces this error

Comment: I tried yesterday. It did not work. Today, it worked. Excellent. Thank you very much. I am in starting stage of python and Could you please explain how to understand this? mainly `.columns[::2]`, `.columns[1::2]` ? I mean, what exactly they are doing?

Comment: See [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation). It gives a nice overview of the topic

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to integer positional slicing, you can use [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to create 2 index objects. Then use `zip` to iterate over them pairwise:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time1', 'Pmpp1', 'Time2', 'Pmpp2', 'Time3', 'Pmpp3'])

times = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Time')]
pmpps = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Pmpp')]

for i, j in zip(times, pmpps):
    print(i, j)

Time1 Pmpp1
Time2 Pmpp2
Time3 Pmpp3
```

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of scenario, it might make sense to reshape your DataFrame. So instead of selecting two columns at a time, you have a DataFrame with the two columns that ultimately represent your measurements.

First, you make a list of DataFrames, where each one only has a Time and Pmpp column:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(1,97):
    tmp = df[['Time{0}'.format(i),'Pmpp{0}'.format(i)]]
    tmp.columns = ['Time', 'Pmpp']  # Standardize column names
    tmp['n'] = i                    # Remember measurement number
    dfs.append(tmp)                 # Keep with our cleaned dataframes
```

And then you can join them together into a new DataFrame. That has three columns.

```
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

This should be a much more manageable shape for your data.

```
>>> new_df.columns
[n, Time, Pmpp]
```

Now you can iterate through the rows in this DataFrame and get the **values** for your expected output

```
for i, row in new_df.iterrows():
    print(i, row.n, row.Time, row.Psmpp)
```

It also will make it easier to use the rest of pandas to analyze your data.

```
new_df.Pmpp.mean()
new_df.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a series of trials, I got it. My code is given below:

```
for a in range(0,len(df.columns),2):
    print(df.columns[a],df.columns[a+1])
```

My output is:

```
DateTime   A016.Pmp_ref
DateTime.1 A024.Pmp_ref
DateTime.2 A040.Pmp_ref
DateTime.3 A048.Pmp_ref
DateTime.4 A056.Pmp_ref
DateTime.5 A064.Pmp_ref
DateTime.6 A072.Pmp_ref
DateTime.7 A080.Pmp_ref
DateTime.8 A096.Pmp_ref
DateTime.9 A120.Pmp_ref
DateTime.10 A124.Pmp_ref
DateTime.11 A128.Pmp_ref
```